# Typedef of a templated class inside itself

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I know the usage of a `typedef`, but I do not understand **when and how** to use `this_type`?

```
template<typename T>
class Foo
{
   public:
      typedef Foo<T> this_type;
      // ...
};
```

An example of its usage or a link would be very helpful as well.

Comment: AFAIK this makes no sense, since plain `Foo` inside that template would just give the same result. Where did you come across this?

Comment: @fatih i found it in my company code..there are other things inside Foo class which I won't paste here for obvious reason. If you need any specific information, I can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

It would have a very narrow use case, possibly only for clarity and consistency over a code base; `this_type` may be a better description than `Foo<T>` in code that may otherwise lack context (for whatever reason). As such, it looks more like a personal or company style over any particular technical requirement. It is worth mentioning though that the name `Foo` is already applicable.

Another case may be to be clear on the distinction between `Foo<T>` and some `Foo<U>` - but again, the use would be limited (e.g. converting constructors).